# Как импортировать пользователей в wordpress из api другого приложения?

Tags: wordpress

Опишите пожалуйста общими тезисами этот процесс. 
Есть ли такая возможность в Wordpress?

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_insert_user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стучите в API. Получаете информацию, затем через `wp_insert_user` добавляете пользователей:

```
$api_response = ...;
$userdata = array(
    'user_login' => $api_response['user'],
    'user_pass'  => $api_response['pass'],
    'user_email' => $api_response['mail'],
    'first_name' => $api_response['name'],
    'nickname'   => $api_response['nick'],
);

$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;
```

https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_insert_user